# text display starting from bottom up qt

Tags: qt

How would I display text in something like `QTextEdit` starting from bottom up? `QTextEdit` starts writing at the top filling down to bottom. I want to start from the bottom and then pushing the previous text up as more text is added. I figure I could hack it and simply fill the field with nextlines to reach the bottom then reprinting whatever was written before again when text is to be added, but I wouldn't want to do that unless there isn't any other way.

Answer (score 0):

[`insertPlainText`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#insertPlainText) inserts text at the current text position. You could move the cursor to the start of the docuement using the [`moveCursor`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#moveCursor) function.

Every time you want to add some text do the following:

```
textEdit->moveCursor(QTextCursor::Start);
textEdit->insertPlainText(textToBeAdded);
```

Comment: `Qt::AlignBottom` doesn't seem to work using `setAlignment()`. The documentation also doesn't list it on the valid values for the function. That got me on the right track though.

Comment: You are right I didn't notice that align bottom was not valid for QTextEdit. Strange enough...